# How to add a "superscripted 2" in resource file

Tags: c#, resources

I need to add a message which contains superscripted 2 into a Global Resource file

I know that unicode for the same is "\u00b2" .

But i how do i add in resorce file so that final message displayed is "Superscripted"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just add it in the designer? Use charmap or whatever other way you want to get the character into the clipboard, and then put it into the textbox in the designer. It's crude, but I've just tried it and it appeared to work.

Comment: I copied superscripted character from word to designer, but no luck.

Comment: @Gaddigesh: What do you mean by "no luck"? Have you tried from charmap? What exactly is the result? Perhaps it's how you're trying to display it.